# Directus headless CMS - Display attributes from 3rd table in dropdown One-To-Many

Tags: database, headless, directus

> Table A = {Student_ID,Student_Name}, Table B = {Teacher_ID,Teacher_Name}, Table C = {Relationship_ID,Student_ID,Teacher_ID}

Table C captures a relationship between A and B and therefore has a many-to-one relationship with both Table A and B. Here we create a visible drop down column with the names of the students and teachers

When creating a table D which has a many-to-one relationship with table C, how can we create a visible drop down column that captures the relationship from table C but with the student- and teacher names when it's not contained in table C?

Answer (score 1):

A great question. Which version of Directus are you using?

This was a bit more complex in v6.x and required some custom code I think. But in the new v7 (which is in RC.3 right now and will be released in the next few days) you can accomplish it with dot notation.

**v7**: In the options of the dropdown, you can choose what data to make visible. If it is not a field on the *actual* item, then you can reference the relational data like this: `actual-field.related-field-to-show`

Using this method you can go as deep as you need: eg `root.level-1.level-2` ... but the more complex and deeper the data, the more time it will take to fetch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using 6.4.. Where would I put the code?

Comment: I'm not an expert on backbone of v6, but I would assume here: https://github.com/directus/directus/blob/master/app/core/interfaces/one_to_many/interface.js

I recommend giving v7 a try if possible. This is all a lot easier in that newer version.